Cartoon series about Scooby Doo competing with other characters?
In my child age I have seen Scooby Doo and I watched some cartoon series where Scooby and his teammates are participating in an event and scoring points. Is it a part of Scooby Doo or is it another cartoon TV series with all the characters?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? When was your child age? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

You're thinking of the Hanna-Barbera Laff-A-Lympics. This was a segment on the Saturday morning *Scoobys' All-Star Laff-A-Lympics show, which also included a few other Hanna-Barbera shows along with it.
The show basically depicted a sports battle between all the Hanna-Barbera "stars" fighting in various Olympic-style athletic contests (it's based of a live-action show called Battle of the Network Stars).

Source: wikipedia, used under Fair use 
of copyrighted material in the context of Laff-A-Lympics

Laff-A-Lympics  immediately comes to mind. This was a show in which many Hanna-Barbera characters would compete in Olympic-style events. It ran in 1977-79, and consisted of twenty-four episodes.

